# JSFiddle: связь между URL и данными, как работает

Tags: url, jsfiddle

Когда мы сохраняем сниппет на JSFiddle, то создаётся новая ссылка с идентификатором типа «u1uc1erz» (`https://jsfiddlenet/u1uc1erz/`), по которому вытаскиваются данные из БД или запускается скрипт-преобразователь во что-нибудь другое. Также видел (опять же, не припомню где), что вместо набора символов из английских букв и цифр, используются только цифры.

Как это реализуется?

Может есть какие специальные классы для этого, чтобы не изобретать велосипед?

Comment: Классы конечно есть под всё на свете. Но тут нет ничего хитроумного, просто генерация случайной строки и изменение текущего URL без перезагрузки страницы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое очевидное: при сохранении **генерируется случайная строка**, которая служит уникальным идентификатором в базе данных (SQL или noSQL). Если сохранение прошло успешно, через pushState этот id добавляется в адресную строку. Непринципиально где создаётся этот id, в браузере или на сервере.

Когда происходит переход по такому адресу, совершается обратная операция: по id вытягивается запись из базы, шаблон заполняется данными.

Пример универсального генератора на JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10727155/272885
Про адрес и pushState: http://htmlbook.ru/html5/history

Comment: А, вот оно что ... Меня сбивало с толку как именно уникальность проверяется. Получается, что если сохранение прошло неудачно, то генерируется новая случайная строка. А может есть мысли как контролировать длину строки: то есть, например, для ситуации, когда все случайные комбинации израсходованы, увеличивать длину (на один символ).

Comment: Замучаетесь расходовать :)

Comment: Согласен. Однако в мире Интернета есть печальный опыт: IP4 :), да и генераторы разные могут быть, так что полностью исключать этот вопрос, думаю, не стоит.

Comment: (26 букв латиницы в одном регистре + 10 цифр) всё в восьмой степени. Довольно большое число. Даже разово натолкнуться на коллизию сложно. Об исчерпании даже не мечтайте. Это космические масштабы .

Comment: Я вот заметил, что на некоторых сайтах, которые реализуют данную штуку, идёт постепенное увеличение длины хеша ... И пришла мысля, как можно контролировать эту длину,.. решил сюда запостить ... Мы можем вычислить количество вариантов и можем сосчитать количество имеющихся записей в БД — исходные данные есть.